# function array with functions from different objects

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c++03

I don't have much experience using array of functions in C++. I need to use an array of functions where the array contains functions from different objects. 
Here is some dummy code to illustrate what I want to implement.

```
class base_class
{
public:
  virtual int function1(int arg1, int arg2);
  virtual int function2(int arg1, int arg2);
};

class derived_class : public base_class
{
public:
  int function1(int arg1, int arg2) { /* ... */ };
  int function2(int arg1, int arg2) { /* ... */ };
  // ...
};

typedef int (*functions) (int arg1, int arg2); 

int main()
{
  derived_class object1;  
  derived_class object2;  

  functions func_instance[4];
  func_instance[0] = object1.function1;
  func_instance[1] = object1.function2;
  func_instance[2] = object2.function1;
  func_instance[3] = object2.function2;
  // ...
}
```

I can't get it to work, it throws following error:

```
error: argument of type int () (int , int) does not match int (*) (int, int)
```

Comment: Look up `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq to understand how the site works. Please mark the best answer to your question as accepted and up-vote accordingly. Have fun :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `std::function` and `std::bind`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <array>

derived_class object1;
derived_class object2;

std::array< std::function<int(int, int)>, 2> > 
  arr = {{ std::bind(&derived_class::function1, &object1)
         , std::bind(&derived_class::function2, &object1)}};
         // and so on
```

Note that `object1` and `object2` have been bound by address. You need to keep them alive as long as the bound functions are alive. If you just write `object1` in the `bind` expression a copy of the object will be stored in the bound function and no scope problems will occur.

**C++03** A complete example with a hand-rolled, single-purpose binder-type:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
  virtual void f0() { std::cout << "f0 base" << std::endl; }
  virtual void f1() { std::cout << "f1 base" << std::endl; }
};

struct derived : base
{
  void f0() { std::cout << "f0 derived" << std::endl; }
  void f1() { std::cout << "f1 derived" << std::endl; }
};

// typedef for a Pointer to a member function 
// of base that accepts arguments and returns void
typedef void (base::*MemberPtrType)(void);

// we pack a pointer to a class and a pointer to a member function together
struct binder
{
  MemberPtrType ptr;
  base*         base;

  // shortcut to call this thing, you might also want 
  // to have an overload of operator() and a result_type typedef
  void call()
  { ((base)->*(ptr))(); }
};


int main()
{
  base b;
  derived d;

  // initialize a 4 element array of binder, the first argument is the function,
  // the second is the object to call it on
  // 
  // remember that b and d need to be alive as long as 
  // you want to call something in this array
  binder arr[4] = { {&base::f0, &b}, {&base::f1, &b}, 
                    {&base::f0, &d}, {&base::f1, &d}};

  // now walk through the array and call each
  for(binder* begin = arr; begin != arr + 4; ++begin)
  {
    begin->call();
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried to adopt this, GCC 4.1.2 does not not have the 'array' header (?). I have to use this compiler. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: @functon It wont have `functional` either. Your alternatives include using the Boost libraries or doing it the painful way. I try to come up with a C++03 solution. But those can be harder to write and maintain then just not doing it at all...

Comment: @functon I added a C++03 example.

Comment: @pmr Well, technically it *will* have the `functional` header, just not the `std::function` type. But sorry for the nitpicking and +1 for the answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau Of course. C++03 `functional` was so useless that I don't even remember it existed.

Comment: @pmr I actually was a fan of it and tried to put its rather limited flexibility to the best use possible. And more often than not it spared me from creating a dumb one-line struct for what should be a small expression inside the actual algorithm call expression. I got so used to that that I still prefer using `std::bind` and `std::mem_fn` over a lambda in certain cases when they're equally well-suited.

Comment: @ChristianRau I used it a lot as well, but at some point accepted that it is very hard for others to maintain, rather unreadable and has tricky quirks. That's why I often exaggerate its uselessness.